# Installing vncserver on manjaro

Tags: vnc, manjaro

I need to install & configure vncserver on the manjaro. I want it configure in such way that if I reboot than also I could connect without starting service and should connect to 0 display not new session.

Answer (score 2):

Install it via the command line:

`yaourt -S realvnc-vnc-server`

Run it and configure (login) with:

`systemctl start vncserver-x11-serviced.service`

If you have problems with no icon being displayed in the system tray (as I did), use:

`vncserver-x11-serviced-fg`

Since Manjaro uses systemd, you can use this to start the daemon automatically at system boot time:

`systemctl enable vncserver-x11-serviced.service`

Note: This is all assuming you have a basic (HOME) subscription.

Please read the [Realvnc docs](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/man/vncserver-x11-serviced.html) for more information.

Comment: what is yaourt? Not available for me.

Comment: yaourt is another package manager similar to yay, you can install both using pacman or any other package manager.

Answer (score 1):

You should get used to looking at the Arch Wiki. I'm going to guess but I think English isn't your first language and that is ok because the Wiki covers most languages and you can just switch it.

This is the site you need,
[This is for TigerVNC](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TigerVNC) 
Now you should know that VNC is not safe if you are using it with other people on your local network or if you want to use it over public internet.

You should take a look at X2GO it is way nicer and easier to setup and also has encryption and passwords.[This is the X2GO Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X2Go)

Comment: There's also x11vnc, I've been using that for about a year and it works very well.